# Help understanding a proof that $[G:H][H:K]=[G:K]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The proposition to be proved was: If $K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and $H$ a subgroup of $G$, then $[G:H][H:K]=[G:K]$, provided these indices are finite.

The proof given was: It is easy to see that each coset $gH$ of $G$ modulo $H$ contains the cosets $g(hK)=(gh)K$ modulo $K$, where $hK$ runs through all the cosets of $H$ modulo $K$.

I've been staring at that proof for a while now, and I just have no idea what it is saying, and how what it is saying is a proof. Would it be possible for someone to explain the proof, in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the family $\{g_1 H,\ldots, g_m H\}$ of all cosets of $G/H$, and the family $\{h_1 K,\ldots, h_n K\}$ of all cosets of $H/K$. What he observes is that each $g_i H$ contains all the cosets $g_i(h_j K)$. In particular, if $i\neq j$, then the families $\{g_i(h_1 K),\ldots, g_i(h_n K)\}$ and $\{g_j(h_1 K),\ldots, g_j(h_n K)\}$ are disjoint. Each of these families have $[H: K]$ elements and we have in total $[G: H]$ such families. So the union of these families has $[G: H][H: K]$ elements.

Finally, it's clear that the union of all these families is precisely $G/K$, so it has in total $[G: K]$ elements and we obtain the desired relation.

Comment: Thank you, its a lot clearer now.

Comment: @user600464 This would be the proof, right?